# Write an audio source filter for use as Lync microphone

Tags: c++, windows, audio, directshow, lync

I'm trying to write a DirectShow Audio Capture Filter that can be recognized by the Microsoft Lync client as a `Microphone` source. These are the steps I've already taken:

1. Filter derives from `CSource`; its output pin derives from `CSourceStream` and implements `IKsPropertySet` and `IAMStreamConfig` and all necessary methods (inc. `IUnknown` methods)
2. Ensure that the appropriate metadata for the `AM_MEDIA_TYPE` and its `WAVEFORMATEX` header are set in `GetStreamCaps()` and `GetMediaType()`
3. In `fillBuffer()`, each media sample is filled with a sine wave test sequence
4. Created the class factory for the COM server and exported DLL functions in a `.def` file, registering the filter under `CLSID_AudioInputDeviceCategory`.

After registering my filter using `regsvr32`, everything currently works in GraphEdit: the filter displays under Audio Capture Devices, and the tone plays correctly.

[image: GraphEdit.exe demonstration]

---

However, I get different results in "real" programs. In Picasa's webcam  tester, for example, the filter displays as an audio source but switching to it crashes the program.

In all versions of the Lync client, the filter doesn't display at all as a `Microphone` choice under `Audio Device -> Microphone`. I've read in the [Lync documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.device.devicemanager.audiodevices_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx) that only virtual audio devices with a physical speaker and microphone are returned.

After looking around some more, it seems that [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) produces the desired effect of being recognized by the system, as shown below:

[image: Lync VAC demo]

---

I require the flexibility of writing my own solution code-wise, which has the added benefit of not needing to purchase a license.

**Do I need to switch to Windows Media Foundation, support additional interfaces in my filter, couple the source filter with a hardware speaker source, etc.?**

**What steps do I need to take to make my filter appear as a `Microphone` source?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lync (Skype for Business) does not use DirectShow for audio capture, so it does not see your virtual device and cannot pick it up. Presumably, it uses WASAPI. Virtual Audio Cable presumably implements a kernel level driver for audio device, which WASAPI picks up and exposes via user mode API. There is no way to connect your virtual audio source to application that does not use DirectShow for audio capture.

Comment: Is it possible to emulate an audio endpoint device in WASAPI? What do you suggest is the best way to approach the problem?

Comment: There is no good ("good" in terms of easy and documented method for this sort of extensibility) way. One way is to hook API calls, WASAPI related, and inject your input/capture device/endpoint. Another is to implement a kernel mode device (see [this](https://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=262539)).

Comment: I'll look into both approaches and research WASAPI in general. For the first, what is the design from a high-level view? Do I somehow intercept the WASAPI calls made by Lync?

Comment: My bet is that Lync does `CoCreateInstance` to access [`MMDeviceEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316556) and then gets audio devices from there. Hooking there is the way to supply your virtual device. In the same time hooking is a "last resort" approach, which can only be sadly suggested when nothing else works out.